# How to create random AES 128 PrivateKey and IV as strings?

Tags: java, security, encryption, aes

What's a simple way to make `AES 128 private_keys` and `init vectors`?

I read it was common practice to use *UUID*, but when I tried to implement:

```
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID() ;
    String private_key = uuid.toString();
```

The error message:

> Invalid AES key length: 36 bytes

tells me that `uuid.toString() = "38400000-8cf0-11bd-b23e-10b96e4ef00d"` isn't 128 bytes.

Also, how would you create a 16 byte Init vector as a string? Can you also use uuid?

Comment: It is important to use standard terminology in order to avoid confusing others and possibly yourself.  The symmetric keys for encryption algorithms like AES are called *secret* keys. For asymmetric cryptography like RSA, you have a keypair consisting of a *private key* and a *public key*.

Answer (score 1):

Keys (encryption generally) is defined over byte byte arrays. You may check [the blog](https://gusto77.wordpress.com/2017/10/30/encryption-reference-project/) for examples

and btw - we are talking about 128 bit (=16 bytes)

> What's a simple way to make AES 128 private_keys and init vectors?

The most secure way is using the SecureRandom class, especially for keys. I wouldn't consider using uuid secure enough (it's not random enough)

```
SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
byte[] key = new byte[KEY_SIZE / 8];
byte[] iv = new byte[SYMMETRIC_BLOCK_SIZE / 8];
rnd.nextBytes(key);
rnd.nextBytes(iv);
```

> How to create random AES 128 PrivateKey and IV as strings?

If you want textual representation of the key or iv (byte arrays), you may encode them, Base64 or Hex are the most common encodings

```
Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(...)
```

Comment: Using your code, with `byte[] key = new byte[128 / 8];` and then `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(...)`  Creates working private keys but gives the error `Wrong IV length: must be 16 bytes long for the IV`.

Comment: @Qwertford you need as well 128 bit (=16 bytes) random IV.  You may have a look at the linked blog with examples. The IV can be created the same way as the key (it should be different from the key)